# Connect GPS module with GPS antenna SIM39EA to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware, gps

I bought a GPS module with GPS antenna SIM39EA online.

The manual for the GPS module is here:

http://www.vis-plus.ee/pdf/SIM39EA_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf

I have an Arduino board. It has 3 ground pin, one Vcc and two input/output pin.

I want to know how can I connect this module to Arduino GPS module and get GPS coordinates?

Comment: Please post a link to the board datasheet, or at least some information about it. Which Arduino do you have?

Comment: here it is the manual of gps module please use this link to download manual   www.vis-plus.ee/pdf/SIM39EA_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf     I am trying to connect it  with Arduino UNO R3 board with DIP ATmega328P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data comes back via the GPS's UART port.
Use the softserial library to create a second serial port on your Arduino (means you can still use the normal serial to read the console).

Then write a program that sucks data from the GPS and squirts it out of the Arduino serial port back to your PC using printf.

I only had a quick flick through and didn't see the default serial speed, so start with 9600 and experiment.

What should come out is probably a line of comma separated values which is in NEMA format.  Google for the specification and you will be able to find out the bits of interest.

Hope that helps.